# What are the differences between "Run as administrator" and a manifest with requireAdministrator?

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, uac, manifest

I've written a program with a manifest that includes requireAdministrator.  On Windows 7 systems with UAC enabled, Windows pops up a dialog asking for permissions, as it should.  Works great.

If a user starts my program by right-clicking it and choosing "Run as administrator", then Windows 7 also pops up a dialog asking for permissions.  However, there are some slight differences in how my program operates in some of the more esoteric parts of my program.

So what are the differences between "Run as administrator" and a manifest with requireAdministrator?  Any links to documentation that describe differences would be appreciated.

**Edit**: This is with UAC enabled.

**Edit**: As promised below is the full explanation of the difference I'm seeing.

I'm using the [EasyHook library](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) to inject a DLL into another process.  When my application is run with "Run as administrator", the injected process crashes and EasyHook returns the error "Unknown error in injected assembler code".  None of the code in my DLL gets a chance to execute; the crash occurs before then.  (Moreover, the crash occurs even if I strip the DLL down to nothing)

If I run my program normally (i.e., elevated via requireAdministrator), everything works fine.

My application is composed of a few different executables.  The process that the user launches is not the same process that performs the injection.

Comment: It might help if you mention what differences you are observing.

Comment: I would not expect any differences at all. (I am also pretty sure that there should be non during runtime of the process.) Maybe you are starting a new process from your process? Then it is no longer *that* obvious that the way in which the first process got its privileges is irrelevant.

Comment: @0xA3: I am really looking to learn what the high-level differences are, not to explain the particular behaviors that I'm seeing.  I only mentioned them to head off answers of "there are no differences".

Comment: @Andreas: My process does indeed start other processes.  Can you tell me what differences there are for the subprocesses?

Comment: Daniel, maybe the differences you are seeing have another explanation than the one you are assuming. That's why I was asking.

Comment: @Daniel: I am afraid that I cannot. I just guessed that any differences might be related to subprocesses. For if we disregard such things, I cannot imagine any differences at all. In both cases, the app is running with raised privileges (the same kind as well); the only thing that differs is how the app got this elevation.

Comment: @0xA3: I see behavior A 100% of the time with "Run as administrator" and behavior B 100% of the time without it (i.e., with permissions via requireAdministrator).  Same machine, same everything, except how I start the program.  I hate to tease anyone's curiosity like this, so I'll post more of the particulars in two days, regardless of whether someone can point me to a high-level description of any differences, okay? :)

Comment: @Andreas: Could there be differences other than differences in permissions?

Comment: As far as I know there are no differences.  I just ran a test with a simple "Hello world" program and in both cases they get exactly the same settings (identical administrative tokens, no virtualization, etc.).  I really don't see how the two methods could differ.  What are you not telling us?

Comment: I too would expect no differences. Manifest, compat settings on the exe, right-click run as admin, launched from a command prompt that you elevated, there are lots of ways to launch it elevated but I would have said elevated is elevated. Looking forward to learning what you see different between them.

Answer (score 3):

With the information given there would be no differences in the permissions between the two processes.

If you request an execution level of "requireAdministrator" via the applications manifest your application will either be launched with the full access token of an administrator or not at all if the user denies consent (see *[Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)* for further information).

The same will happen when a user chooses *Run as Administrator*.

The only difference is the way that the process is started. When you start an executable from the shell, e.g. by double-clicking in Explorer or by selecting *Run as Administrator* from the context menu, the shell will call `ShellExecute` to actually start process execution. The whole process of elevation is hidden inside this function. Kenny Kerr describes this process in more details in *[Windows Vista for Developers – Part 4 – User Account Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/09/29/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-4-_1320_-User-Account-Control.aspx)*:

> ShellExecute first calls CreateProcess to attempt to create the new process. CreateProcess does all the work of checking application compatibility settings, application manifests, runtime loaders, etc. If it determines that the application requires elevation but the calling process is not elevated then CreateProcess fails with ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED. ShellExecute then calls the Application Information service to handle the elevation prompt and creation of the elevated process since the calling process obviously doesn’t have the necessary permissions to perform such a task. The Application Information service ultimately calls CreateProcessAsUser with an unrestricted administrator token.
>
> If on the other hand you want to create an elevated process regardless of what application information is available then you can specify the little-known “runas” verb with ShellExecute. This has the effect of requesting elevation regardless of what an application’s manifest and compatibility information might prescribe. The runas verb is not actually new to Windows Vista. It was available on Windows XP and Windows 2003 and was often used to create a restricted token directly from the shell. This behavior has however changed. Here is a simple example:
>
> ```
> ::ShellExecute(0, // owner window
>            L"runas",
>            L"C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe",
>            0, // params
>            0, // directory
>            SW_SHOWNORMAL);
> ```

So essentially starting an executable using the *Run as Administrator* option means that `ShellExecute` bypasses the checks for compatibility settings, application manifests etc and directly requests elevation.

Kenny Kerr's article also has sample code to query the current process' token for its permission using the `OpenProcessToken` function. Possibly you can use the example to identify that there are no differences in the way your process is elevated.

I'm definitely curious to know which differences you are observing as I strongly doubt they are related to elevation.

As a last thing: Can you double check that you really request a level of  *requireAdministrator* and not by mistake only a level of *highestAvailable*?

Comment: I double checked and it's set to requireAdministrator.

Comment: Could there be subtle differences in the behavior between CreateProcessAsUser and the runas verb? (whether related to elevation or unrelated things such as environmental variables)

Comment: @Daniel Stutzbach: Sorry to repeat myself, but when you like to get help then please don't hide all the relevant information you have. We're not here to play games, aren't we? With the information you provided my above answer is as much as I can help you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

One possible difference might be the rarely used/understood/deliberately-chosen uiAccess attribute. Can you create two manifests, one with uiAccess=false and one with uiAccess=true, then tell us whether one of them gives the same behaviour as you see with right-click-run-as-admin?

Comment: If that would be the case then @Daniel Stutzbach should really be ashamed of not telling us what his application is doing or not doing correctly. However, from my understanding this setting should not have any effect here. Setting `uiAccess` to true allows the application to talk to higher privilege windows on the desktop, but as it is already running with highest privileges there should be no windows with even higher privileges.

Comment: Right now I'm using uiAccess=false.  I'll try uiAccess=true and report back.

Comment: with uiAccess=true, requireAdministrator has the same behavior as before.  However, "Run as Administrator" changed behavior to match requireAdministrator.  * confused *

Comment: @Daniel so maybe it's time to be clear about what you saw as differences? You may have just been running two versions of the app.

Comment: @Daniel Stutzbach: Could you solve the problem meanwhile? Or will you give an update?

Answer (score 1):

The EasyHook documentation for the RemoteHooking class' IsAdministrator property mentions:

*Due to UAC on Windows Vista, this property in general will be false even if the user is in the builtin-admin group. As you can't hook without administrator privileges you should just set the UAC level of your application to requireAdministrator.*

It's hard to imagine why this is happening, but it is conceivable (especially as you are seeing it happen!) that assets, processes, assemblies, &c, with possibly different trust levels and so forth, will not inherit the elevation of your main app.  Setting the requireAdministrator flag may handle/enforce this globally across the entire scope of resources and dependencies. Would love to know how this turns out.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was seeing a difference between these as well. However, it turned out that in my case the issue was this:

When I click "Run as Administrator" from my file browser (Q-Dir), the working directory is different than when I try simply double clicking an application with `requireAdministrator` set in the manifest. This changed the behavior of some buggy DLLs I had received. In fact, it turned out that 100% of the differences I saw were due to running from different working directories (specifically, it mattered whether I was on C: drive or a different drive letter) and that the method of getting the program to run as administrator had nothing to do with it.

It's an issue that is specific to my computer's exact configuration, but it is a possible clue into the type of thing that might be happening (or might have happened 7 years ago . . .  )